# WSL - Find out build release version

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to find out the current build release for WSL i.e. [Build 15042](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-15042) - I wish to update to this build, followed the steps and am unsure if it has worked.

Comment: can you explain your steps used to update WSL ?

Comment: You need to update your windows using the Windows 10 Update Assistant. [This link should hopefully help you](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-upgrade-assistant)

Comment: its a shame, have to opt in for developer preview and update your whole system :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to check the version installed in your system (after updating to Windows Insider to get a more recent WSL, I asume), check your Windows build in `dxdiag`, or with `ver` in console.  Or you can also directly check bash.exe's details by right-clicking it and looking at its Properties (you can find it in %WINDIR%\System32).

Answer (score 0):

From within WSL distrib, you can run:

```
cmd.exe /c "systeminfo" | grep "^OS Version"
```

It will give you your OS version which correspond to WSL build.

Comment: from WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04: `$ cmd.exe /c "systeminfo" | grep "^OS Version"
cmd.exe: command not found`. `which cmd.exe` gives nothing. `whereis cmd.exe` gives nothing.

Comment: You might have to mount your c drive:
`which cmd.exe`

`/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/cmd.exe`